# Is this the correct answer for getting the Taylor Polynomial of $f(x) = e^{3x}$ at $p_{3}(2)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let  $f(x) = e^{3x}$

Find $P_{3}(2)$

So,

$f^0(2) = e^{3x} = e^6 $

$f^1(2) = e^{3x}*3 = e^{6}*3$

$f^2(2) = e^{3x}*3^2 = e^{6}*3^2$

$f^3(2) = e^{3x}*3^3 = e^{6}*3^3$

So the expansion would be:

$ = e^6 + e^6(3) / 1!*(x-2)^1 + e^6(3^2) / 2!*(x-2)^2 + e^6(3^3) / 3!*(x-2)^3 $

Is this correct or wrong?

Thank you

Comment: As I've seen that notation, $P_n(x)$ is the nth degree Taylor expansion evaluated at $x$, whereas you are *expanding* about $2$ and evaluating at $x$

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if I were suppose to expand or just give that particular place in the series. So instead do you think it should be: $e^6(3^3) / 3!*(x-2)^3$ ?

Comment: $P_{3}(2) = e^6(3^3) / 3!*(x-2)^3$

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. Were you given a parameter to expand about? When it's not specified, I usually expand about $0$ (what's called a *McLaurin* series).

Comment: If you were supposed to expand about $2$, then your original answer is correct.

Comment: Oh yes, I thought that's what the 2 in the $P_{3}(2)$ meant. About a = 2.

Comment: nth term evaluated at about a = 2. I think....